# jquery bind submit event - find caller

Tags: javascript, jquery, binding

How would I be able to find out the caller/sender of an event on binding.

```
$(this).bind("submit", function(caller) { ... });
```

I found out that I could use "caller.originalEvent.explicitOriginalTarget", but this only works in firefox.

EDIT:

I'm using the jquery validation library from position-relative.net I want to make it so that if a button has a class called "bypass" on the sender, that makes the validation engine just return true so the form can be submitted. I.e. I'm using ASP.NET, and all button presses are postbacks (form submits). I'm just looking to make a back button.

I've added this code

```
if ((caller.originalEvent.explicitOriginalTarget != null) && (caller.originalEvent.explicitOriginalTarget.className == "bypass")) {
            return true; 
        }
```

on line 71, just under this line

```
$(this).bind("submit", function(caller) {   // ON FORM SUBMIT, CONTROL AJAX FUNCTION IF SPECIFIED ON DOCUMENT READY
```

Thoughts and suggestions appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 10):

**Update:** Per your comment below, you're looking to see *which* submit button triggered the submission. You can't do that with the form's `submit` event — but you can with the `click` event on your submit buttons:

```
$(this).find("input[type=submit]").click(function() {
    var bypass = $(this).hasClass("bypass");
});
```

The submit button's `click` event happens before the form's `submit` event, so you can use that to set a flag, and then use that flag in the form's submit handler. The flag can be in JavaScript code somewhere, a hidden field on the form, an attribute you add to the form element, etc.

The following information about `target` vs. `this` is probably no longer directly relevant to your question, but I'm leaving it because people who need to understand `target` vs. `this` will probably find your question, so it may be useful to them.

**`event.target`** is the element on which the event actually occurred. For bubbling events, this may be a descendant of the element on which you've attached a handler:

```
$(this).bind("submit", function(event) {
    var target = event.target;
});
```

**`this`** is the element on which you set the event handler (this is [ensured by jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)):

```
$(this).bind("submit", function(event) {
    // `this` is the element you hooked the event on
});
```

Since you're using a `submit` event and hooking the form directly, I'd expect `target` and `this` to be the same.

**Three examples** (two regarding forms, one just general)

**1.A. Example with form submit and JavaScript variable** ([live version](http://jsbin.com/azume3/5)):

Here's an example that uses form submit, differentiates between `target` and `this`, and shows hooking up the submit buttons' click events so we know whether they have the class "bypass". This uses a flag in the JavaScript code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Target Example</title>
<!--[if IE]>
  <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<style>
  article, aside, figure, footer, header, hgroup,
  menu, nav, section { display: block; }
  body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <form id='theForm' action='#'>
    <input type='submit' value='Send 1' class='bypass'>
    <input type='submit' value='Send 2'>
  </form>
  <hr>
</body>
<script type='text/javascript'>
jQuery(function($) {
  var form, bypass;

  // Our bypass flag
  bypass = false;

  // Get the form
  form = $('#theForm');

  // Hook up click handlers on the submit buttons
  // to update the bypass flag.
  form.find('input[type=submit]').click(function() {
    bypass = $(this).hasClass('bypass');
  });

  // Hook up a form submission handler
  form.submit(function(event) {
    // Either do validation or don't, as appropriate
    display("event.target.tagName = " + event.target.tagName +
            ", this.tagName = " + this.tagName +
            ", bypass = " + bypass);

    // Best to reset the flag here in case submission is
    // cancelled and then the form is re-submitted using
    // something other than a submit button (the user
    // pressing Enter in a text field, or you calling the
    // submit function)
    bypass = false;

    // Just returning false in this example
    return false;
  });

  function display(msg) {
    $("<p>" + msg + "</p>").appendTo(document.body);
  }

});
</script>
</html>
```

**1.B. Example with form submit and attribute** ([live version](http://jsbin.com/azume3/6)):

This is the same example as the above, but using an attribute instead of a flag in the JavaScript code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Target Example</title>
<!--[if IE]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<style>
article, aside, figure, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, section { display: block; }
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form id='theForm' action='#'>
    <input type='submit' value='Send 1' class='bypass'>
    <input type='submit' value='Send 2'>
</form>
<hr>
</body>
<script type='text/javascript'>
jQuery(function($) {
var form;

// Get the form
form = $('#theForm');

// Default to no bypass
form.attr("data-bypass", "N");

// Hook up click handlers on the submit buttons
// to update the bypass flag.
form.find('input[type=submit]').click(function() {
    $(this.form).attr("bypass",
                    $(this).hasClass('bypass') ? "Y" : "N");
});

// Hook up a form submission handler
form.submit(function(event) {
    var form = $(this);

    // Either do validation or don't, as appropriate
    display("event.target.tagName = " + event.target.tagName +
            ", this.tagName = " + this.tagName +
            ", bypass = " + form.attr("bypass"));

    // Best to reset the flag here in case submission is
    // cancelled and then the form is re-submitted using
    // something other than a submit button (the user
    // pressing Enter in a text field, or you calling the
    // submit function)
    form.attr("bypass", "N");

    // Just returning false in this example
    return false;
});

// We're done with the `form` jQuery obj, release it
form = undefined;

function display(msg) {
    $("<p>" + msg + "</p>").appendTo(document.body);
}

});
</script>
</html>
```

**2. Example with a difference between `target` and `this`** ([live version](http://jsbin.com/azume3/2)):

This example is no longer relevant to your question, but I'm leaving it in place for anyone needing an example of `target` vs. `this`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Target Example</title>
<!--[if IE]>
  <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<style>
  article, aside, figure, footer, header, hgroup, 
  menu, nav, section { display: block; }
  body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <p id="one">I'm one, and <strong>this is a child element</strong></p>
  <p id="two">I'm two, and <strong><em>this is two children deep</em></strong></p>
  <p id="three">I'm three, there are no child elements here</p>
  <hr>
</body>
<script type='text/javascript'>
jQuery(function($) {

  $('p').click(function(event) {
    display("event.target.tagName = " + event.target.tagName +
            ", this.tagName = " + this.tagName);
  });

  function display(msg) {
    $("<p>" + msg + "</p>").appendTo(document.body);
  }

});
</script>
</html>​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Comment: It seems like I do not have that member.
These are all the members I see available.
http://img836.imageshack.us/img836/2240/clipboard02kq.jpg

Comment: @Mike: That's very strange, you should have it if you're using jQuery. jQuery normalizes the event object for you. I've tested the above on IE6 and IE8 on Windows, and Chrome, Opera, and Firefox on Linux. All fine. If you post some further code we may be able to help you figure out what's going wrong.

Comment: I'm using jQuery, with the Validation Engine from position-relative.net I'm trying to modify the jquery.validationEngine.js so that if a button has a "bypass" class on it, the validation engine will return true on the form to allow it to postback.

Comment: target seems to be the actual form itself. Still can't find the sender :-(

Comment: @Mike: Ah! Okay, I don't think anyone here understood what you meant by "sender" in that context. You can't do that with the form `submit` event. Instead, you need to hook the `click` event on the submit button and set a flag (either a flag in code somewhere or a hidden field on the form). If I get a chance, I'll do an example in a little bit.

Comment: That would be very much appreciated. I've tried to change the validationEngine.js code to a $(".submitbutton").bind("click" etc.. but it does not want to fire anymore, and all the logic that was in the $(this).bind("submit", function) is referencing "this", which is not the form anymore. Aragh!

Comment: Thank you so much. Your answer is the best I have ever seen on stack overflow. Your help is so greatly appreciated. It's help like this that makes the programming community thrive. I have learned so much more over the weekend regarding jQuery and html forms, which has resulted from your answer! You are a legend, Sir!