# Identify submit button in the form from jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I want to do a different function when i submit a form from different button. My form is following.

```
<form action="status_submit" method="get" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <button type="submit" name="approve">Approve</button>
    <button type="submit" name="reject">Reject</button>
    <button type="submit" name="cancel">Cancel</button>
</form>
```

I tried following code. But is not working.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('form').submit(function(event) {
            var val = $("button[type=submit][clicked=true]").attr('name');

            alert(val);

            if (val == 'approve') {
                alert('approve');
            } else if (val == 'reject') {
                alert('reject');
            } else if (val == 'cancel') {
                alert('cancel');
            }

            return false;
        });        
    });
</script>
```

Always val in undefined. How can i do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery bind submit event - find caller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776033/jquery-bind-submit-event-find-caller)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$(this)` to reference the clicked button.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form button[type="submit"]').click(function(event) {
        var val = $(this).attr('name');

        alert(val);

        if (val == 'approve') {
            alert('approve');
        } else if (val == 'reject') {
            alert('reject');
        } else if (val == 'cancel') {
            alert('cancel');
        }

        // Submit form
        $('form').submit();

        return false;
    });        
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't track it like that.... the solution could be is to use the click handlers for the buttons

A dump solution can be

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('button[name="approve"]').click(function(){
        //do stuff
        $(this).addClass('clicked');
    })
    $('button[name="reject"]').click(function(){
        //do stuff
        $(this).addClass('clicked');
    })
    $('button[name="cancel"]').click(function(){
        //do stuff
        $(this).addClass('clicked');
    })

    $('form').submit(function(event) {
        var val = $("button.clicked[type=submit]").attr('name').removeClass('clicked');

        alert(val);

        if (val == 'approve') {
            alert('approve');
        } else if (val == 'reject') {
            alert('reject');
        } else if (val == 'cancel') {
            alert('cancel');
        }

        return false;
    });        
});
```